# Using Ionic2 with firebase auth

Tags: cordova, ionic2, cordova-plugins

I tried to use Ionic 2 with firebase auth using this:

```
signInWithFacebook(): firebase.Promise<FirebaseAuthState> {
    if (this.platform.is('cordova')) {
      console.log("trying to log in using cordova...");
      Facebook.login(['email', 'public_profile']).then(res => {
        console.log("Logged in. result here");
        const facebookCredential = firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(res.authResponse.accessToken);
        console.log(firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(facebookCredential));
        return firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(facebookCredential);
      });
    } else {
      return this.auth$.login({
        provider: AuthProviders.Facebook,
        method: AuthMethods.Popup
      });
    }
  }
```

This code works great in web, but doesn't work in Android (Cordova).

I debugged why the login button is not working and I found this errors:

> EXCEPTION: Error in ./HomePage class HomePage - inline template:6:0
>   caused by: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined....
>
> Logged in. result here
>
> EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: firebase is not
>   defined ReferenceError: firebase is not defined
>       at file:///android_asset/www/build/main.js:42039:42
>       at t.invoke...

Regards the second issue (firebase is not defined) I tried to

```
`import firebase from 'firebase';`
```

but Ionic 2 build returned error.

I just used the code in the Angularfire2 auth using Ionic 2.

Anyone has any idea why it might happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not returning `Facebook.login()`. So I believe it returns error when you try to access it in your component.

```
  return Facebook.login(['email', 'public_profile']).then(res => {
```

Comment: It solve the issue, but returns the wrong data. I need to return this: `firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(facebookCredential)`

Comment: if ``firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(facebookCredential);`` returns a promise with the information you require, you would receive that  in the returned promise in ``signInWithFacebook()``